# Restricting a generic parameter in the scope of a method

Tags: java, generics, api-design

Let's say that we have a `class Foo<T>` which represents some operation that produces a value of type `T`. I would like to be able to compose two objects of this class in the case that one produces a `Function<A, B>` and the second one produces an `A` to get a `Foo<B>`. I can do that with the following static method:

```
public static <T, U> Foo<U> compose(Foo<Function<T, U>> fn, Foo<T> x) {
    // the composition is an implementation detail
}
```

Now I can easily compose a `fooAtoB` of type `Foo<Function<A, B>>` with a `fooA` of type `Foo<A>` like this:

```
compose(fooAtoB, fooA)
```

Unfortunately, in my case it is common for `Foo` to produce nested functions like `Function<A, Function<B, Function<C, D>>>` and I'd like to be able to compose these with `Foo<A>`, `Foo<B>` and `Foo<C>` to get a `Foo<D>`.

I can do that with the following:

```
compose(compose(compose(fooAtoBtoCtoD, fooA), fooB), fooC);
```

This works, but there's a lot of nesting and the readability suffers because of that. Ideally, what I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
fooAtoBtoCtoD.compose(fooA).compose(fooB).compose(fooC)
```

But as far as I can tell, it's impossible to express such a thing, as there's no way to name the return type of `compose`, because `compose` has no way of knowing whether or not the `T` in `Foo<T>` is actually a `Function<U, V>`.

It's quite easy to do it the other way:

```
<U> Foo<U> compose(Function<T, U> fn)
```

But this is, again, not very nice to use.

```
fooC.compose(fooB.compose(fooA.compose(fooAtoBtoCtoD)))
```

The arguments are written from right to left and there's lots of nesting.

This brings me to the question:

Is there a way to restrict `Foo`'s `T` parameter to a subset of types only in the scope of the `compose` method so that it can take advantage of that restriction?

Something that would allow me to express the following would be great:

```
T extends Function<U, V> in the scope of
<U, V> Foo<V> compose(Foo<U> x) {
    // values of type T are convertible to Function<U, V>
    // in the scope of this method
}
```

Right now I think that nothing like that exists and that the proof of `T` being a function must come from the outside when calling `compose`, so something like this:

```
<U, V> Foo<V> compose(Function<T, Function<U, V>> fn, Foo<U> x) {
    // I can use fn#apply to convert a T to a Function<U, V> here   
}
```

works fine when given the identity function:

```
fooAtoBtoCtoD.compose(x -> x, fooA).compose(x -> x, fooB).compose(x -> x, fooC)
```

But it's a bit too long and repeating `x -> x` all over is not fun.

A solution to that might be to package the function together with `Foo`. Given the following class:

```
class FooWithIdentity<T, U> extends Foo<T> implements Function<U, U> {
    @Override
    U apply(U val) {
        return val;
    }

    ...
}
```

and the following two methods in `Foo`:

```
<P extends Foo<U> & Function<T, Function<U, V>>, U, V> Foo<V> compose(P foo)
{
    Function<U, V> fun = foo.apply(value);
    return new Foo<>(fun.apply(foo.value));
}

<U> FooWithIdentity<T, U> wrap() {
    return new FooWithIdentity<>(this);
}
```

I've achieved the following:

```
fooAtoBtoCtoD.compose(fooA.wrap()).compose(fooB.wrap()).compose(fooC.wrap())
```

Which is, in my opinion, the best solution so far.

**EDIT:** Radiodef's solution gave me an idea for a simpler solution with the same interface:

```
class Foo<T>
{
    ...
    <U> U through(Function<Foo<T>, U> fn) {
        return fn.apply(this);
    }

    <U> Function<Foo<Function<T, U>>, Foo<U>> composing() {
        return fooFn -> /* compose fooFn and this here */;
    }
}
```

Essentially, `through` just takes a function and runs `this` through it and `composing` produces a function that does the actual composition, together they can be used like this:

```
Foo<D> fooD = fooAtoBtoCtoD
    .through(fooA.composing())
    .through(fooB.composing())
    .through(fooC.composing());
```

Answer (score 1):

Another variant would be to make e.g. the following methods:

```
class Foo<T> {
    ...
    <U> Foo<U> map(Function<T, U> fn) {
        return new Foo<>(fn.apply(this.value));
    }
    static <T, U> Function<Function<T, U>, U> composing(Foo<T> t) {
        return fn -> fn.apply(t.value);
    }
}
```

That would let you do e.g. this:

```
Foo<D> fooD =
    fooAtoBtoCtoD.map(composing(fooA))
                 .map(composing(fooB))
                 .map(composing(fooC));
```

([Here's a working example.](https://ideone.com/XWuhiP))

That's not really any shorter, but it's a little more clear about what it's doing.

As for the hope of something like `abc.compose(a).compose(b)`, not in Java at the moment, unfortunately.

I think it would be possible in principle for the Java compiler to support some kind of instance method-level generics like `<A,B> where 'this' must be a Foo<Function<A,B>>`, though. It doesn't require anything more than checking the type of the reference at the method call site, so it's not like erasure prevents it.

Usually when Java is missing a generics feature it's because erasure makes it impossible to implement, like generic constructor calls, but I don't think that's the case here. The method body (which requires `T` be a `Function`) could erase to casts like `((Function) this.value).apply(a)`.

Comment: This is a reasonable solution, although it's not without its problems - `composing` needs to be able to turn the `Foo<T> ` directly into a `T`, which is impossible in my case, as composition needs to pass additional state through each `Foo`.

But it gave me an idea, see my edit above.

Also, I agree with your last three paragraphs, I am also quite sure that this could technically be done in the language itself without any need to extend the JVM.

Comment: I'd appreciate an upvote if you found the idea useful. If you end up using the solution in your edit (or something else), you could think about posting it as an answer too.

Comment: Upvote given.

I'll think about other solutions and if I'm not able to come up with anything better, then I'll post my own answer.